# sharedPreferences - saving background color between sessions

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

sorry for newbie question but I'm starting with Kotlin and Android app development. Currently I'm trying to create simple Activity that will switch background colors. I add 2 buttons that are working and switching colors between white and green, but would you be able to help me how to save it between the session using sharedPreferences ? I cannot retrieve these states from the preferences. Code sample below:

```
class OptionsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options)

        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("bgColour", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = prefs.edit()

        bt3.setOnClickListener {
            Screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
        }

        bt4.setOnClickListener {
            Screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the color in your preferences:

```
val prefs = getSharedPreferences("bgColour", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

//Retrieve the saved value, default is false.
if (prefs.getBoolean("isGreen", false)) {
    Screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
} else {
    Screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
}
        
val editor = prefs.edit()


//Save on button click
bt3.setOnClickListener {
    Screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
    editor.putBoolean("isGreen", true)
    editor.apply()
}

bt4.setOnClickListener {
    Screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    editor.putBoolean("isGreen", false)
    editor.apply()
}
```

You can read more about saving key-value pairs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).